# How Can I edit a custom field in CRM Content

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a pre made app where in I need to change a field in the current CRM Content. I want to view the custom fields of the existing CRM Content but unfortunately I don't know how even with the use of google.

Well for example I have a Matter__c object, when I upload it the data will be transferred to a salesforce crm content page. Now my goal is to be able to Implement ability to add Users to Content as Author instead of fixed Workspace Administrator. Now my problem is I can't find where I can do that. Well I am just a beginner when it comes to salesforce and I am not that used to it.

[image]

Comment: The more detail you give us, the better we can assist you. Especially if you [edit] it into your posts instead of dropping it in the comments, which are ephemeral and easy to gloss over.

Comment: Okay my bad. Sorry I just used salesforce stack exchange yesterday.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! In case you haven't already, there are great resources in the [faq] and [help]. Specifically here, [ask] has some useful tips.

Comment: Soooo can you help me now with my question? haha

Comment: Well...do any of the object descriptions below match up with what you're trying to do? If you can include some urls and/or screenshots in your post that outline what you're trying to accomplish through the UI, that can help also.

Comment: Well some the fields matches the ContentVersion and ContentWorkspaceDoc. So How can i access those object?

Comment: You should be able to query any of them...Are you trying to write a page? Batch? Trigger? You can click through any of the links to see what fields these objects have and build a `SOQL` query with that information.

Comment: Give us the URL! It contains so much information!

Comment: I already added a screenshot of my salesforce crm content page to my question. Thank you so much for your time. I am actually stuck with this task for 2 days.

Comment: Is my screenshot okay now?

Comment: That tells me nothing, though others may find it useful. **What is the url for that page?**

Comment: Well can I just explain it to you? 

The data comes from a custom object called Matter__c now when I try to upload it, The data will be stored in a Salesforce CRM Content. The author will be a fixed workspace Administrator. Now what I want to know is how can I edit the "AUTHOR" field into a look up where in I can choose other users to be an Author. Now my problem is I can't find that certain Salesforce CRM Content Page where in I can see/edit the fields.

Comment: Why won't you share the url? It likely tells you the Id, which you can use to get the `SObjectType`, using `system.debug(Id.valueOf('<id_here>').getSObjectType())`.

Comment: https://netops--contract.cs16.my.salesforce.com/sfc/#version?selectedDocumentId=069f00000004sIJ that is the url well my bad.

Comment: It is in the ContentDocument. Now how can I access the custom fields of that said Object?

Comment: I can't migrate the comments, but any further discussion should take place in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45047/content-author).

Comment: I need 20 reputation points to be able to talk in chat @AdrianLarson

Comment: Hmm, I thought I could explicitly give you write access even without 20 rep but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: and yeah just to answer your question. I finally gained access to the object contentDocument using the workbench and I tried updating the ownerID/Author of an existing data and I think that it is not possible so I'll confirm it first to my onshore. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a great many objects involved, depending on what you are trying to accomplish. I listed them here in order of how long they have been available.

> ## [CombinedAttachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_combinedattachment.htm?search_text=crm%20content)
>
> This read-only object contains all notes, attachments, Google Docs, documents uploaded to libraries in Salesforce CRM Content, and files added to Chatter that are associated with a record.
>
> ## [ContentWorkspace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm)*
>
> Represents a public library in Salesforce CRM Content. This object is available in versions 17.0 and later.
>
> ## [ContentWorkspaceDoc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspacedoc.htm)*
>
> Represents a link between a document and a public library in Salesforce CRM Content. This object is available in versions 17.0 and later.
>
> ## [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)
>
> Represents a specific version of a document in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files. This object is available in versions 17.0 and later for Salesforce CRM Content documents. This object is available in versions 20.0 and later for Salesforce Files.
>
> ## [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)
>
> Represents a document that has been uploaded to a library in Salesforce CRM Content or Salesforce Files.This object is available in API versions 17.0 and later for Salesforce CRM Content. This object is available in API version 21.0 and later for Salesforce Files.
>
> The maximum number of documents that can be published is 6,000,000. Archived files count towards this limit and towards storage usage limits.
>
> - Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance Edition customers can publish a maximum of 36,000 new versions per 24–hour period.
> - Developer Edition and trial users can publish a maximum of 2,500 new versions per 24–hour period.
>
> ## [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)
>
> Represents the link between a Salesforce CRM Content document or Salesforce file and where it's shared. A file can be shared with other users, groups, records, and Salesforce CRM Content libraries. This object is available in versions 21.0 and later for Salesforce CRM Content documents and Salesforce Files.
>
> ## [ContentDistribution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm)
>
> Represents information about sharing a document externally. This object is available in API version 32.0 and later.
>
> ## [ContentDistributionView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistributionview.htm?search_text=crm%20content)
>
> Represents information about views of a shared document. This read-only object is available in API version 32.0 and later.
>
> ## [ContentFolder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentfolder.htm)
>
> Represents a folder in a content library for adding files. This object is available in API version 34.0 and later.
>
> ## [ContentFolderMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentfoldermember.htm)
>
> Defines the association between a file and a folder. This object is available in API version 34.0 and later.
>
> ## [ContentFolderLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentfolderlink.htm)
>
> Defines the association between a library and its root folder. This object is available in API version 34.0 and later.
>
> * <sub><sup>This object does not apply to documents and versions in a personal library.</sup></sub>